# 'host.json' file values in Azure function application are not updating properly when hosting it into Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-functions

I have a 'ServiceBusTrigger' type azure function app, which I am planning to host into Kubernetes. It was hosted in azure earlier, we have made some custom settings in 'host.json' file. Now, when I host it into Kubernetes, it doesn't take the values from 'host.json' as it is. Instead, it always sets the default value mentioned as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#additional-settings-for-version-5x).

This is the value which I set in source,
[image]

But this is what k8s log shows,
[image]

Not only highlighted values, but other values are also not updating properly from what we have given in the source. If anyone faced this issue, kindly help me to overcome this situation.

Comment: It would be best to check the container that is being built. You are likely copying over the wrong `host.json`